# Python : What is a string array?

Tags: python, arrays, string

So I'm doing this coding challenge in Python and the problem says that the input is a `string array`. I downloaded a sample input, and the `.txt` file is like this:

```
13
Alice;START
Bob;START
Bob;1
Carson;START
Alice;15
Carson;6
David;START
David;24
Evil;START
Evil;24
Evil;START
Evil;18
Fiona;START
```

Honestly, I don't know how to process that input to obtain individual rows from it as pairs of items, so I failed the challenge badly. However, I'm still interested in learning.

I tried to process the input using `split(";")`.

Any ideas how to parse this input?

Comment: "arrays" aren't really a thing in Python (I mean sure, they are, but you don't use them because lists are so much nicer). What was the output supposed to be?

Comment: The output should be `11;Evil;SHORTENED_JOB`, because `Evil` started a job with ID less than the previous started job (IDs are incremental), where `11` is the line number

Comment: The input is a *file* containing text; read the file contents into relevant internal data-structures. The use of "string array" in any instructions, while unfortunate, does not imply an implementation and would be better conveyed as "n lines, as specified by the first line, where each line is a semi-colon separated pairs of.. etc etc" - solutions will use appropriate data-structures per the *specific* language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("your_file.txt") as f:
    array = [line.rstrip().split(";") for line in f]
```

---

**The explanation:**

The first line is a safe way to open a text file. (The file will be automatically closed after the work).

`f` at the end of that line becomes the name of the *iterable* object - with every iteration we obtain the *full next line* from the opened text file.

Now we use that object for creating the list by a List Comprehension (the second line) - see the end of that line:

```
                                      for line in f]
```

Because the `line` contains the full line, i. e. with trailing newline (`\n`) symbol, we use the `rstrip()` method to trim it out:

```
            [line.rstrip()            for line in f]
```

And finally we split every such string into a list (using the delimiter symbol `;`)

```
            [line.rstrip().split(";") for line in f]
```

and assign the result to the variable `array`:

```
    array = [line.rstrip().split(";") for line in f]
```

---

The test:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(array)
```

The output:

> ```
> [['13'],
>  ['Alice', 'START'],
>  ['Bob', 'START'],
>  ['Bob', '1'],
>  ['Carson', 'START'],
>  ['Alice', '15'],
>  ['Carson', '6'],
>  ['David', 'START'],
>  ['David', '24'],
>  ['Evil', 'START'],
>  ['Evil', '24'],
>  ['Evil', 'START'],
>  ['Evil', '18'],
>  ['Fiona', 'START']]
> ```

---

**Note:**

The first line of your text file contains the number 13 - it is probably the number of remaining lines. If you want ignore it, just append the `[1:]` to the second line of code:

```
with open("your_file.txt") as f:
    array = [line.rstrip().split(";") for line in f][1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no enough details but I would assume that the first line is the number of examples and the following lines contain the tuples which are, in fact, the string array you mentioned.

I would go the following way:

```
with open ("input.txt") as f:
   no_examples = f.readline().strip()
   array = []
   for i in range(no_examples):
      example = f.readline().strip().split(';')
      array.append(example)
```

The assignment to `example` variable strips the invisible line end characters and splits the result by the separator `;`.